# Groovy in SOAPUI Asserting on repeating nodes located by expected data

Tags: groovy, soapui

Below is an example response to explain my scenario

```
              <ns2:Details xmlns:ns2="http://ww">
                 <ns2:Code>011</ns2:Code>
                 <ns2:Result>4</ns2:Result>
              </ns2:Details>
              <ns2:Details xmlns:ns2="http://ww">
                 <ns2:Code>018</ns2:Code>
                 <ns2:Result>0</ns2:Result>
              </ns2:Details>
              <ns2:Details xmlns:ns2="http://ww">
                 <ns2:Code>098</ns2:Code>
                 <ns2:Result>2</ns2:Result>
              </ns2:Details>
```

The data that I am interested in testing here is contained in `ns2:Result`. I already know what value I am expecting in this node, but it has to be associated with the correct `ns2:Code` value.

For instance, to make this test pass I would expect

- expect `Code 011` when `Result is 4`
- expect `Code 018` when `Result is 0` and so on.

So the data I already know is Code and Result, but I need to ensure that the correct Result values are being returned for each Code. I don't need to verify what Code's are returned, I just need to verify the Result figures against the correct Codes.

Comment: Matt, please check the solution to see if that resolves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an expected result as a map as below which is combination of `Code and Result`, so that both can be verified / asserted together.

```
['011': '4', '018': '0', '098': '2']
```

Use **Script Assertion** for the same request test step.

Here goes the script:

```
//assert if there is response
assert context.response, 'Response is null or empty
//change below map as needed
def expected = ['011': '4', '018': '0', '098': '2']
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def actual = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'Details'}.collectEntries{[(it.Code.text()): it.Result.text()]}
assert expected == actual
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks (again!). The only thing is that the assert for the context.response seems to make the test fail. It works as expected if I comment out that row.

Comment: @Matt, this works if you have already run the service, it fails because there is no reponse, appreciate if you can upvote previous accepted answer as well.

Comment: The service is already run. No probs though, I'll take a closer look at that down the line. I suppose it's more of a safety net to capture non responses though rather than genuine data fails. I'll upvote your other one now. Thanks again, this is really helping me on my journey.