# Identifying multiple values in SOAP UI response with Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I was recently helped through a problem here where I wanted to identify multiple values from a SOAPUI response. This was successfully answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556839/groovy-in-soapui-asserting-on-repeating-nodes-located-by-expected-data).

I tried to take this same approach to a new problem I have. This time I would like to pick up 4 values from each section to use as my expected results.

Below is an example of my response that I want to run the assert expected results against:

```
       <ns1:LimitAndUsageDetailsList>
          <ns2:LimitAndUsageDetails xmlns:ns2="http://www.">
             <ns2:LimitCode>022</ns2:LimitCode>
             <ns2:LimitCodeDesc>APPLIANCES</ns2:LimitCodeDesc>
             <ns2:LimitType>N</ns2:LimitType>
             <ns2:LimitBenefit>500.0</ns2:LimitBenefit>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitUsed>0.0</ns2:LimitBenefitUsed>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitAvailable>500.0</ns2:LimitBenefitAvailable>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitService>0</ns2:LimitBenefitService>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitUsedService>0</ns2:LimitBenefitUsedService>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitAvailableService>0</ns2:LimitBenefitAvailableService>
             <ns2:QualifyingPeriodIndicator/>
             <ns2:ClaimIndicator>B</ns2:ClaimIndicator>
             <ns2:LimitPeriod>1</ns2:LimitPeriod>
             <ns2:LimitPeriodType>C</ns2:LimitPeriodType>
             <ns2:LimitScale>INDIV</ns2:LimitScale>
          </ns2:LimitAndUsageDetails>
          <ns2:LimitAndUsageDetails xmlns:ns2="http://www.">
             <ns2:LimitCode>023</ns2:LimitCode>
             <ns2:LimitCodeDesc>NEBULISER</ns2:LimitCodeDesc>
             <ns2:LimitType>N</ns2:LimitType>
             <ns2:LimitBenefit>0.0</ns2:LimitBenefit>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitUsed>0.0</ns2:LimitBenefitUsed>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitAvailable>0.0</ns2:LimitBenefitAvailable>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitService>1</ns2:LimitBenefitService>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitUsedService>0</ns2:LimitBenefitUsedService>
             <ns2:LimitBenefitAvailableService>1</ns2:LimitBenefitAvailableService>
             <ns2:QualifyingPeriodIndicator/>
             <ns2:ClaimIndicator>B</ns2:ClaimIndicator>
             <ns2:LimitPeriod>3</ns2:LimitPeriod>
             <ns2:LimitPeriodType>R</ns2:LimitPeriodType>
             <ns2:LimitScale>INDIV</ns2:LimitScale>
          </ns2:LimitAndUsageDetails>
```

And I am interested in `LimitCode, LimitType, LimitPeriod and LimitPeriodType` elements.

I have tried the following assert script but it doesnt work.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

def expected = [
"022":"N":"1":"C"
'023':'N':'3':'R',
'030':'N':'1':'C',
]
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)


def actual = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'LimitAndUsageDetails'}.collectEntries{[(it.LimitCode.text()): it.LimitType.text(): it.LimitPeriod.text(): it.LimitPeriodType.text()]}
assert expected == actual
```

Comment: try the solution and see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do.

- Expected data requires couple more items as opposed to previous question.
- So need to create map(to identify which data to what element)
- Since there are list of details to be verified, expected data should be list of maps.

Please see the `Script Assertion` below:

```
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

//list of maps; each map for single usage detail
//If the details are more, you may use a csv data file; solution may vary slightly
def expected = [ 
   [ LimitCode: '022', LimitType: 'N', LimitPeriod: 1, LimitPeriodType: 'C'],
   [ LimitCode: '023', LimitType: 'N', LimitPeriod: 3, LimitPeriodType: 'R']
]   
 
 
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.respone)

//Build the actual list of map from response
def actual = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'LimitAndUsageDetails'}.collect{ [
                   LimitCode       : it.LimitCode.text(),
                   LimitType       : it.LimitType.text(),
                   LimitPeriod     : it.LimitPeriod.text() as Integer,
                   LimitPeriodType : it.LimitPeriodType.text()
                ]
               }.sort {it.LimitCode}
assert expected == actual
```

You may quickly try the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/0XDosd)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks so much for this really thorough response. I'm just working through this now and digesting the new approach. I initially tried to run this assert before adjusting it to fit my scenario but it fails will a 'null' message which doesn't give me much to go on. I will keep searching some ideas why I may be getting this but through it worth replying straight away in case you knew of a fix for this.

Comment: OK. I found the issue and fixed it and this script works perfectly. I can use this for the basis of a bunch of tests now so I will get on to this. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code which is also to get Response node values in

```
def groovyutils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder=groovyutils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent)

holder.namespaces["ns"]="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"

def conversionRate=holder.getNodeValue("//ns:ConversionRateResult")
```

i was not able to test on your code since i dont have the correct namespace, but this code works perfectly fine for getting a value from response of currency convertor

you just need to change xpath inside getNodeValue and the namespace URL. this way its simpler